# Use $push operator on document with mongoDB GODriver without creating separate arrays

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I currently have some GO code that looks like this:

```
   _, err = swapStruct.ReferenceCollection.UpdateByID(ctx, swapStruct.ReferenceID, bson.D{
        {"$push", bson.D{{"students", objIDs}}},
    })
```

to insert an array of objectIDs, to a specific document, under the "students" key.  In that document though, it ends up being inserted under the "students.0" key. How do I insert the "objIDs" array into this document under the "students" key instead of it
being under the "0" array under the student key?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$push` pushes a value to an array. With your code, you are pushing an array as a single element. To push the values of an array, use `$each`:

```
{"$push", bson.M{"students": bson.M{"$each": objIDs}}}
```